# Format date as 03/14/2018 in C# or HTML5

Tags: c#, razor

[image]

I want date format like **03/14/2018**(ie., March 14 2018) I tried like this in Razor view

[image]

Getting result like this 
if any other way is there please share me

Comment: Come on, you can easily look this up

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Replace:

```
public void Replace{
      String.Replace("-","/"); 
}
```

This will replace every dash with a slash.